# Error using chown

Tags: command-line, chown

I am a complete newbie, so please forgive my ignorance.

Could someone please help with this error.  Thank you very much for any help.  Much appreciated.

```
(trusty)epaschall@localhost:/usr/share/Minecraft$ sudo chown -hR $USER
chown: missing operand after 'epaschall'
```

have tried `help --chown` and putting in my username... but nothing is working

Comment: What are you trying to change the ownership *of*? you haven't told it (or us)

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `chown` for which files you recursively want to change the owner, like

```
sudo chown -hR $USER .
```

if you want to change the owner of the current working folder (`/usr/share/Minecraft`) or

```
sudo chown -hR $USER *
```

for all files and folders inside this folder but not the folder itself.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Awesome!  I didn't realize i had to include space and then a . (period) at the end.